# Row height of the uitableview in differing gradually

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have two uitableviews in a view controller. First table is set on a uiscrollview programatically and the other table on self.view from storyboard. I have set the rowHeight for both the table as 45. But gradually the height of one table keeps increasing as the rows increase like the screenshot I have shown.

[image: Screen shot 1]

[image: Screen shot 2]

Code goes like this :

```
scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 45, self.view.frame.size.width-130, self.view.frame.size.height-45)];
    scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.42 green:0.27 blue:0.60 alpha:1.0];
    tableGradeValue = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-75) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableGradeValue.delegate = self;
    tableGradeValue.dataSource = self;
    self.tableCourse.delegate = self;
    self.tableCourse.dataSource = self;
    tableGradeValue.rowHeight = 45;
    scrollview.bounces = NO;

    for(int i = 0; i< [res6Keys count]; i++)
    {
        CGFloat y = i * 150;
        UILabel *lblCell = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(y, 1, 140, 31)];
        lblCell.tag = i+1;
        [scrollview addSubview:lblCell];
        lblCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lblCell.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.93 green:0.92 blue:0.96 alpha:1.0];
        lblCell.text = [res6Keys objectAtIndex:i];
    }
    [scrollview addSubview:tableGradeValue];
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
```

And the other tableview is set from storyboard normally and the rowHeight is 45.

Comment: UITableview is inherited from scrollview so why did you put it on a scrollview. Really didn't get that one?!

Comment: Because the tableview on the scrollview is scrollable both horizontally and vertically and there is a title row at the top which is not a part of the tableview but still kept on the scrollview but still scrolls along with the table horizontally so that it gives an MSExcel look.

Comment: @LeoJoseph Can you please post some code to have a better understanding of where you are going wrong?

Comment: did you set header/footer height? please check those as well in both cases.

Comment: Better option then doing this would be go for UICollectionView which would provide you both vertical and horizontal scroll, and help you reach ur goal with some nice looking app. Just a suggestion ,rest is upto you!

Comment: No header and footer for any table. I have done such projects before too but I am facing this for the first time. In the above screenshot, the topmost row and the first column is fixed.

Comment: @walle84 This is suggested by the client. Its may be some minor mistake which I am not able to find.

Comment: Okay then I guess you need to play-off with height of left side tableview so as to match up and also I will have a look into it on my side. If I get something I would definitely post up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wether this was the problem. But strangely I got the answer. I dint give @property and @synthesis to the table which was over the scrollview. I now gave property and synthesis and it got working.

Comment: `@synthesis`...? where did you get this one?

Comment: \@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableGradeValue;

\@synthesize tableGradeValue;

Comment: yep, the `@synthesize` and the `@synthesis` are definitely not the same. the first one is a correct keyword, the second one is just something which has never existed in _Objective-C_.